# Curl - Exclamation mark in User Auth/Password

Tags: bash, curl, escaping

Having a problem with CURL and the HTTP User and password Auth methods, it is not liking the exclamation mark, I've tried escaping the following ways:

Tried and failed...

```
/usr/bin/curl -u 'UserName\WithSlash:PasswordWithExclamation!' https://test.com/
/usr/bin/curl -u UserName\\WithSlash:PasswordWithExclamation\! https://test.com/
```

Not working for basic or digest if it matters (using --anyauth) ... getting 401 denied...

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Out of curiousity, have you tried just using the username and letting curl prompt for the password, or using the `--netrc` opt and putting the username and password in a .netrc file?

Comment: .netrc is looking to work so far...

Comment: What version of bash are you using? I have a feeling that I may have seen this behavior under a very old version of bash (can't give you a version number). For another example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291692/irix-bash-shell-expands-expression-in-single-quotes-yet-shouldnt

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
 curl -u UserName\\WithSlash:PasswordWithExclamation\!  http://....
```

works fine.

it sends

```
 GET / HTTP/1.1
 Authorization: Basic VXNlck5hbWVcV2l0aFNsYXNoOlBhc3N3b3JkV2l0aEV4Y2xhbWF0aW9uIQ==
 User-Agent: curl/7.21.0
 Host: teststuff1.com:80
 Accept: */*
```

which is "UserName\WithSlash:PasswordWithExclamation!" in the auth string.

Answer (score 2):

not that complicated, just use "". at least it works on Linux.

for example:

```
curl -u "username:passwdwithspecialchar" GET https://....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the server supports `Basic` auth, you could set the header directly:

```
curl --header "Authorization: Basic $(base64 --wrap=0 credentials)" https://example.org
```

This way you can store the user and password (`UserName\WithSlash:PasswordWithExclamation!`) without any escaping in the `credentials` file you pass to the `base64` command.